# Python save string to postgres from bytea

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x

i'm a pythonic user. right now, i'm in trouble with restoring "string" into postgres. here's part of my code:

```
dataRecv = '3231334744323031363030313831340000000000'
device_id = bytearray.fromhex(dataRecv[0:(len(dataRecv)-10)]).decode()
```

and i got:

```
device_id = '213GD2016001813'
```

just like what i want.

but then i want to save it to postgresql with pyscopg2:

```
execute("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (device_id)")
commit()
```

which the "column" data type is char(20).
The Error i got is here:

```
syntax error at or near "GD2016001813"
213GD20160018...
   ^
```

i already tried with casting string to the device_id with *`str(device_id)`* and also add apostrophe (') in the beginning and the end of device id so it will be like this: `VALUES ('device_id')`. but the result still the same, wether it will be error from this part:

```
213GD20160018...
   ^
```

or this part:

```
213GD20160018...
^
```

can you guys help me? thankyou

Comment: sorry, i had succeed solved my problem. thankyou.

Comment: Actually, the request "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES (device_id)" should add "device_id" in column "column". Are you sure you pasted the right SQL ?

Comment: `execute("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('device_id')")`?..

Comment: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Answer (score 0):

1)Converting to string https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html
2)Check format of column maybe it takes only numbers